# Create and Publish Azure classic Cloud Service project with AzureRM powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

Even after looking at the docs, I couldn't find a way to do this with the AzureRM powershell cmdlets. Does anyone know how to do this?

The old Azure Service Management powershell cmdlets have a Publish-AzureServiceProject, but I believe it is deprecated now.

---

### **EDIT: Supplement Answer to yoape's answer below**

You can create a new classical cloud service project using something like this:

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames" -Location "centralus" -ResourceName "myCloudServiceProjectName"  -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup"
```

Where `Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames`  is the magic sauce one needs to create the desired classic cloud service project.

However, (afaik) you will still need to deploy/publish the classic cloud service via the old cmdlet: `Publish-AzureServiceProject`. Using the above cmdlet lets you create the cloud project in the proper resource group though.

Comment: you can publish with arm cmdlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic compute services are [basically **not** supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services#compute) by the Azure Resource Manager model. This means you cannot use the [AzureRM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/AzureRM.Resources/v2.0.3/AzureRM.Resources?redirectedfrom=msdn) for publishing your Cloud Services.

The [Publish-AzureServiceProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.compute/v3.4.0/publish-azureserviceproject) cmdlet from ASM is not depricated (yet), you can still use it (in fact it is still the only way to publish your Cloud Service from PowerShell). Perhaps you where thinking about the [deprecation of the Switch-AzureMode](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell) cmdlet?

Comment: How do I create a new azure service project and map it to a specific resource group using the old Cmdlets?

Comment: I found the magic sauce: `New-AzureRmResource -Location "centralus" -ResourceName "myCloudServiceProjectName" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames" -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup"`

Comment: @4c74356b41 please elaborate, what is wrong here? Also, it is based on how the cmdlets looked in Feb '17.

Comment: has nothing to do with cmdlet(s). like rysama showed you it can be done in arm with a specific api call, nothing changed since that time. all the calls are still there (and were there)

Comment: Publish-AzureServiceProject is still what you need to actually *publish* a cloud service project, there is no "ARM way" of doing that. When it comes to creating the resources the you _can_ user New-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines" -xxx. Also, look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model for how to deploy classic services. New-AzureRmResource is not covered as an option.